# Is there a prdefined name for the following solution search/optimization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, iteration, mathematical-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

Consider a problem whose solution maximizes an objective function.
 
Problem : From 500 elements, 15 needs to be selected (candidate solution), Value of Objective function depends on the pairwise relationships between the elements in a candidate solution and some more. 
The steps for solving such a problem is described here:

```
    1. Generate a set of candidate solutions in guided random manner(population) //not purely random the direction is given to generate the population 
    2. Evaluating the objective function for current population
    3. If the current_best_solution exceeds the global_best_solution, then replace the global_best with current_best
    4. Repeat steps 1,2,3 for N (arbitrary number) times
```

where size of population and N are smaller (approx 50) 
    After N iterations it returns a candidate solution stored in global_best_solution

- Is this the description of a well-known algorithm?
- If it is, what is the name of that algorithm or if not under which category these type of algorithms fit?

Comment: Are the candidate solutions created based on the current best solution (i.e. some form of "mutation") or are they created from scratch? In the first case, it's some form of hill-climbing; in the latter case, it's the same as generating all the candidates from all the generations at once and picking the best one.

Comment: Well, it's unusual (and likely less effective) not to do any sort of local search, but I guess this could be considered [random search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search) with an infinite search neighborhood.

Comment: @tobias_k its not from scratch, a search space is found (which is a set of elements) in every iteration and then some random combinations are generated to form candidate solutions. Finding the search space is a guided process which comes up with a space where the probability of having optimal solutions is high

Answer (score 3):

What you have sounds like you are just fishing. Note that you might as well get rid of steps 3 and 4 since running the loop 100 times would be the same as doing it once with an initial population 100 times as large.

If you think of the objective function as a random variable which is a function of random decision variables then what you are doing would e.g. give you something in the 99.9th percentile with very high probability -- but there is no limit to how far the optimum might be from the 99.9th percentile.

To illustrate the difficulty, consider the following sort of Travelling Salesman Problem. Imagine two clusters of points A and B, each of which has 100 points. Within the clusters, each point is arbitrarily close to every other point (e.g. 0.0000001). But -- between the clusters the distance is say 1,000,000. The optimal tour would clearly have length 2,000,000 (+ a negligible amount). A random tour is just a random permutation of those 200 decision points. Getting an optimal or near optimal tour would be akin to shuffling a deck of 200 cards with 100 read and 100 black and having all of the red cards in the deck in a block (counting blocks that "wrap around") -- vanishingly unlikely (It can be calculated as 99 * 100! * 100! / 200! = 1.09 x 10^-57). Even if you generate quadrillions of tours it is overwhelmingly likely that each of those tours would be off by millions. This is a min problem, but it is also easy to come up with max problems where it is vanishingly unlikely that you will get a near-optimal solution by purely random settings of the decision variables.

This is an extreme example, but it is enough to show that purely random fishing for a solution isn't very reliable. It would make more sense to use evolutionary algorithms or other heuristics such as simulated annealing or tabu search.

Comment: Great answer. One correction: a 100 TSP is not like flipping 200 times and getting 100 heads followed by a 100 tails. A tour of 100 locations has a search space of `100! ` which is `10^157`. So it's probably **similar to winning the lottery 15 times in a row**. See [also this](http://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2014/03/27/IsTheSearchSpaceOfAnOptimizationProblemReallyThatBig.html).

Comment: The point is that there are 100 + 100 = 200 cities, have of which are from A and half of which are from B. The near optimal solutions correspond to permutations in which all 100 A-cites are listed before all 100 B-cities or vice-versa (with the order within each cluster essentially irrelevant). It isn't exactly like flipping a coin 200 times (because of the lack of independence) but it was similar enough for the intuition. A better description might be like having a deck of 200 cards, 100 red and 100 black, shuffling them and then having all the red cards be above all the black cards.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I edited the answer to include a probability calculation which I think is correct.

Comment: @ John Coleman The problem is like 500 elements out of which 15 needs (candidate solution) to be selected. The value of the objective function depends on the pair-wise relation between elements and some more. So I chose this method and it provided better solution than evolutionary algorithm. Edited my question: the strategy to select the candidate candidate is not purely random,its a guided random method

Comment: @PremJith It isn't surprising that there are some problems for which this is okay. The No Free Lunch Theorems in some sense predicts the existence of such problems. Getting back to what I said about 99.9th percentile -- if the distribution of possible evaluations has a short tail then this will get you pretty close to a max. Still -- I suspect that there must be *some* mutation operator for which an evolutionary approach performs better.

Answer (score 0):

why do you work with a population if the members of that population do not interact ?

what you have there is random search.

if you add mutation it looks like an Evolution Strategy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy